# How can i set responsive height to my div children?

Tags: css

I have a parent div with class right with (position , Relative). 

 In (right) I have five div.cover with (position , Relative) . How can I set device height to covers? And how can I set (right) height to device height * 5 ?

[image]

**I Cant remove position , Relative to my classes.**

Thanks and sorry about my terrible English

Comment: How about using the `vh` unit? (i.e. `100vh` is 100% of device's screen height).

Comment: See a [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/8knofbbs/) :)

Comment: Thanks for all, know I'm sorry I forget to say it. I have an other div .left , this div need to come down 4 * cover.height !! i can right margin-top: -500vh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [vh unit](http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design).

"VH" stands for "Viewport Height". It's the actual viewport height. 100vw = 100%, 50vw is 50% of viewport height, and so it goes.

You can read later about vh, vw, vmax, vmin, etc.